# Newly contributed theme not showing in Project Application issue queue

Tags: community-official-site

I have contributed a theme ([Auro](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/aryashreep/2637820)) in Drupal.org and assigned for "Needs review" but the project not showing in [Project Application issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/projectapplications?text=&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All).

Why doesn't my theme appear in the Project Application queue? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear because you didn't create an issue in the Project Application issue queue, but in the issue queue for your theme.
To create a issue in that queue, go to https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/projectapplications and click on [*Create a new issue*](https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/projectapplications).

Since I am a Drupal.org webmaster, I have already moved the issue in the correct queue; you don't need to do anything more.